# I cannot query my ontology using Jena Sparql with Java?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I have an issue querying my `owl` ontology file it shows only table with subject and object labels but no classes, properties...

The program can successfully read the ontology but I need to get some data from my ontology.

Does anyone of you has a solution? Please I need it fixed as soon as possible. I'll appreciate that.

Here is my Code:

```
package ontologypro;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OntologyPro  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

        // 
        String filename = "C:/Actor.owl";
        Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        OntModel model1=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);

        try {
            File file=new File(filename);
            FileInputStream reader=new FileInputStream(file);
            System.out.println("The absolute path of the file is:"+ file.getAbsolutePath());

            model.read(reader, "RDF/XML");
            model.close();

            // Create a SPARQL query from the given string.
            String queryString = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>  "+
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" +
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
            "PREFIX act: <http://www.semanticweb.org/project/ontologies/2016/0/Actor#>" +
            "select ?subject ?object "+
            "where { "+
            " ?subject rdf:type ?object "+
            "} \n ";

            Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

            try ( // Execute the query and obtain results
                QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1)) {
                com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();

                // Output query results
                ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
                qe.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }         
    }
}
```

[**Here is the query is input: Please follow the link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V2RX.png)

Comment: Are you getting any error? What's the problem with the code posted?

Comment: No errors but when i query the ontology i get nothing; i already created classes, data properties, object properties, some instances with protege. Even with Sparql protege i cannot get results which is yet another problem!! Any suggestions ?

Comment: Change "QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model)" from QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1)

Answer (score 0):

The code loads data into `model` but queries `model1`.  `model1` is empty.

Comment: so How to fix it please ? @AndyS

Comment: You must be joking...what about simply querying the object `model` in your code?